# optimal network configuration

Tags: networking, router, internet

I am adding an extra line (line B) with a static IP to my house and hosting 3 PCs and a server that some users will remote into.  I want to see if it matters where I place the router in this configuration.  I need to powerline the internet from where it enters to where the PCs are.  So it's internet - modem - powerline - router - switch - PCs.  The Draytek router can't take a DSL connection directly so the modem will be the ISP's router with DHCP off.

[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeSfE.png)

<strike>1. Does internet - modem - router - powerline - switch - PCs make a difference?</strike>

2. Is there any point of getting more powerlines and putting them in parallel?

<strike>3. The server has 4 ethernet ports, should they all go via the switch or some to the switch and some to the router or no difference?</strike>

4. Further complication: I have an existing internet connection (line A) but with no static IP.  The Draytek router is dual wan, is there much point connecting both my internet lines to the Draytek?

EDIT: Removed two questions following feedback from Rich

Comment: You'll want the router as close to the modem as possible, as you'll need NAT and firewall before you reach your internal network

Comment: Ah yes - of course - good point.